# Does Bitcoin still use the IRC channel?

Tags: bitcoin-core, irc

I recently read an [article on Bitcoin Media](http://bitcoinmedia.com/the-irc-bootstrap-method-is-flawed/), that claimed:

> Jeff Garzik pointed out that Bitcoin-Qt no longer operates using the IRC bootstrap, and on inspection he’s right. This mainly applies to older versions of bitcoin.

Implying that the IRC channel is no longer used by Bitcoin-QT. Is this true, and if so, which version of the standard Bitcoin client was the first not to use the IRC channel?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The IRC bootstrapping method is deprecated and default off since the 0.6 release. It's still implemented and can be enabled using the -irc command line option.

The function of the IRC bootstrapping system will get replaced by DNS seeding and peer exchange, however.

Comment: And the dns seed can be disabled using:
"Don't bootstrap list of peers using DNS"
-nodnsseed 

 - http://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin

Related: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Satoshi_Client_Node_Discovery#Discovery_Methods

Comment: is there a more in depth description of dns seeding and peer exchange available?